# Why cant I extract a single column using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a (theoretically) simple task. I need to pull out a single column of 4000ish names from a table and use it in another table.

I'm trying to extract the column using pandas and I have no idea what is going wrong. It keeps flagging an error:

`TypeError: string indices must be integers`

```
import pandas as pd

file ="table.xlsx"
data = file['Locus tag']
print(data)
```

Comment: Seems like you forgot to actually load the file to a dataframe. `file ="table.xlsx"` does not magically do it for you

Comment: As stated above, `file` is a string. You can't index a string with characters.

Comment: You can load Excel data into a DF using [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html).

Comment: @DeepSpace Oops! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just add file name and define the path . But you cannot load the define pandas read excel function . First you have just the read excel function from pandas . That can be very helpful to you read the data and extract the column etc

1. Sample Code

   ```
   import pandas as pd 
   import os 
   p = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath("C:\Car_sales.xlsx"))
   name = 'C:\Car_sales.xlsx'
   path = os.path.join(p, name)
   Z = pd.read_excel(path)
   Z.head()
   ```
2. Sample Code

   ```
   import pandas as pd 
   df = pd.read_excel("add the path")
   df.head()
   ```